# JSP does not render java list in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I have a simple java app in Spring Boot 2 with JSP.
I use h2 database for testing data.
It works fine but JSP does not render the list data from the controller.
The list in JSP is empty, while in the controller it has 2 values. Other properties like String are working fine.
I cannot understand where the problem is.

> Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/users")
public String getUsers(ModelMap map) {
    this.userService.getAll().forEach(user -> System.out.println("user: " + user));
    map.addAttribute("users", this.userService.getAll());
    return "/users";
}
}
```

> User model:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String country;

    public User(@JsonProperty Long id, @JsonProperty String firstName, @JsonProperty String lastName, @JsonProperty String country) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

> JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="title" value="LIBRARY - Users"/>
    </jsp:include>
        <!--NAVBAR-->
        <%@ include file="navbar.jsp"%>
        <!--CONTENT-->
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">        
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Index</th>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" varStatus="iteration">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${iteration.index}</td>
                            <td>${user.id}</td>
                            <td>${user.firstName}</td>
                            <td>${user.lastName}</td>
                            <td>${user.country}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <c:if test="${empty users}">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <p>There are no records in the database</p>
                </div>            
            </c:if>
        </div>    
    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
```

> Debug from the controller:

```
user: User(id=111111, firstName=Wick, lastName=England, country=John)
user: User(id=111112, firstName=Madman, lastName=USA, country=Andy)
```

> UserService.cls returns List from h2 and it is in the debug, it
>   looks fine.

```
@Transactional
public List<User> getAll() {
    return (List<User>) this.userRepository.findAll();
}
```

> Screenshot:

[image]
What could be the issue here?

Comment: The user model class is not included in jsp file.

Comment: @reporter good point, I added the imports but the behavior is the same.
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="library.libraryapp.model.User"%>
The table is still empty.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash JSP name is users, it is the same as the property name "users".

Comment: I am not sure but can you replace this portion: `  map.addAttribute("users", this.userService.getAll());` with delcaring a list and assign that list in your you model like what you have here?

Comment: @user404 I have tried that already but it did not help ;(
I even create inner tmp class with the same properties and added that to list to get rid of User.cls relation, but it did not help...

Comment: ok. another suggestion from me then, change your `modelMap` to `ModelAndView` and return `modelAndView` instead of string and change related things like adding object etc

Comment: @user404 did that, no luck ;(
List<User> users = this.userService.getAll();
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/users");
mav.addObject("users", users);
return mav;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line at the top in your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Also, replace

```
return "/users";
```

with

```
return "users";
```

Comment: I have this added in my header.jsp

Comment: no, it does not work. And the docs say it should return resource mapping which should be "/users". It can be wrapped in ModelAndView object as well.

Comment: those links are not helpful at all, I mentioned in the ticket that String type is being rendered successfully. 
The problem is with List type of java class object.

Comment: have you even checked my code? My code is just the same, it does not work. The list is empty in JSP and there is a check for empty there.

Comment: I had my "c" taglib added in header.jsp with other general tags that I import on every page. However, it did not seem to work, so I added it to the current page and it started working. I marked this answer as the best one, thanks.